# help interpreting an abstract algebra test question

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

This is a take-home test problem, and I don't want help solving it, just understanding what it's asking.  I've asked my prof a couple times, but she's either unwilling or unable to give me a straight answer, and I don't understand why.  The problem:

> Suppose that $f(x)=x^n+a_{n-1} x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$. If $r$ is rational and $x-r$ divides $f(x)$, prove that $r$ is an integer.

My question:  It's my understanding that when you say "$t$ divides $s$" you need to specify what domain you're in.  So they say that "$x-r$ divides $f(x)$", I'm confused about the domain, since $f(x)$ being an element of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is implying polynomials with integer coefficients, while $r$ being rational doesn't seem to fit with that.  Are they saying that $f(x) = (x-r)$ (another element of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$), or is it $f(x) = (x-r)$ (an element of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$)?

Answer (score 5):

You are told that $f(x)$ is in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, and that $f(x)$ is $x-r$ times an element of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.  You are to deduce that $r$ must be an integer. The fact that $f(x)$ is *monic* (the lead coefficient is $1$) is crucial.

Answer (score -2):

In a general Euclidean domain, given x,y in $R$, there are $q, r$ in $R$ with: $$a=bq+r $$ .

IF $r=0$ , then we say $b$ divides $a$. From Wiki's Euclidean Domain. $\mathbb Z[x]$ is a Euclidean domain. Notice that $\mathbb Z$ is embedded in $\mathbb Z[x]$ as the constant polynomials, so that integers are actually part of $\mathbb Z[x]$. IF $r$ is Rational; $r=p/q$ , you can always multiply through by $q$ to get an integer.

Comment: What's wrong with this?

Comment: Thanks for the constructive input.

Comment: I think the downvoters feel that it does not necessarily answer the question and perhaps provides an unsolicited hint on a test question.

Comment: @user153841: Thanks; you may be right, I just think it would be nice for them to give some basic input, which I can correct if I agree with the input.

Comment: But, why is it too much to ask to have someone give a specific comment to this effect; it is not as if I am purposefully or knowingly giving an unfitting answer. How am I supposed to figure out the problem others see in it without feedback? Besides, you don't see these downvoters looking at other questions and upvoting the ones they believe are good, for the sake of being fair; they focus on what's wrong.